# Efficient way to obtain a device mountpoint from its UUID

Tags: linux, shell-script, mount, uuid, lsblk

In a script I'm working on, a variable UUID must be used in obtaining the current mountpoint a device is attached to. The solution I came up with is this one:

```
UUID='fc70ae3d-65e7-4437-a371-b237c8ca3f56h'
MNTPNT=$(lsblk -o +UUID | grep ${UUID} | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 7)
```

*Upon executing the command, variable MNTPNT stores the current mountpoint as expected*. It is a rather extensive command, though, and I can't help but thinking that there must be a more efficient way of achieving the same objective.

Is it possible to come up with a better solution? It would be a matter of optimization, mostly. Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
findmnt -noTARGET "/dev/disk/by-uuid/$UUID"

grep "$(stat -Lc '%#t %#T' "/dev/disk/by-uuid/$UUID" | xargs printf '%d:%d')" /proc/self/mountinfo

awk -v dev="$(stat -Lc '%#t %#T' "/dev/disk/by-uuid/$UUID" | xargs printf '%d:%d')" '$3~dev{print$5}' /proc/self/mountinfo
```

In order to trim bind-mounts:

```
awk -v dev="$(stat -Lc '%#t %#T' "/dev/disk/by-uuid/$UUID" | xargs printf '%d:%d')" '$3~dev&&$4=="/"{print$5}' /proc/self/mountinfo
```

Keep in mind that devices can be mounted in multiple places.

The `$(stat ... | xargs printf)` monstruosity is only because `stat(1)` isn't able to print the major, minor numbers in *decimal*. Just parsing the output of `ls -Hl` would be probably better (and much more portable).

Comment: I understand these solutions might work, but are they supposed to be more efficient?

Comment: You have to definie "efficient". You're not going to list mount points in a tight loop, 10k times / second ;-) But yes, `findmnt` is the most efficient, because it does everything in C in a couple of system calls, without starting a dozen processes. The awk and grep are to give ideas to people who want to do that on embedded machines, where there's no `lsblk`, `findmnt, etc.

Comment: Even your `lsblk` can be done much better with `lsblk -no UUID,MOUNTPOINT | awk -v "uuid=$UUID" '$0~uuid&&$2!=""{print$2}'`. So if you came here to have your solution validated -- the answer is NO.

Comment: I like the one using findmnt. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
df | grep "^$(readlink -f /dev/disk/by-uuid/$UUID) " |sed 's/^[^%]*% \+//'
```

This works also when bind-mounts are present of subdirectories of the mount, which might confuse some other potential solutions.

(Edit:)
Allow spaces in mountpoint.

(Edit2:)
Mountpoint may contain "% " as well.